# browser not rendering a font before the textbox is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

So I have a text box which is modified via jQuery/angularjs and alghough the text field .text() changes and the text is displayed in Dev Tools, the text does not appear.

Only when I click on the text box and then click somewhere else does the text appear.
Interesting thing is that the 'Rendered fonts' section appears only after the `click -> click somewhere else` scenario has happened.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cDoIzSG.png]

I'm on windows 8.1 using Chrome 48

EDIT: This is not Chrome specific. The same behaviour is on latest Firefox.
What would be a possible cause for a bug?
What I do not get is why does clicking on the textbox and then clicking somewhere else trigger rendering of the font

Comment: Do you have an URL with the code? It'll be easier to identiy the problem.

Comment: Yeah an issue is that this code should not be disclosed and I'd say this would be hard to reproduce in plunker. I'll see what I can do